# Laravel store and update form

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I would like to update a form, I mentioned that the form is already saved in the database(function store). I want to edit the form and update it in the database(function update).
I only want to UPDATE the "tags", this is giving me an error because it is in another table.

I would need your help because I can't do it, I tried different methods but didn't succeed.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // process the listing creation form
        $validationArray = [
            'title' => 'required',
            'company' => 'required',
            'logo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:9048',
            'location' => 'required',
            'service' => 'required',
            'apply_link' => 'required|url',
            'content' => 'required',
            'payment_method_id' => 'required'
        ];

     

        if (!Auth::check()) {
            $validationArray = array_merge($validationArray, [
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
                'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:5',
                'name' => 'required',
                'phone' => 'required|numeric|min:10|starts_with:0'
            ]);
        }

        $request->validate($validationArray);

        // is a user signed in ? if not, create one and authenticate
        $user = Auth::user();

        if (!$user) {
            $user = User::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
                'phone' => $request->phone
            ]);
            
            $user->createAsStripeCustomer();

            Auth::login($user);
            
        }

        // process the payment and create the listing
        try {
            $amount = 9900; // $99.00 USD in cents
            if ($request->filled('is_highlighted')) {
                $amount += 1000;
            }

            $user->charge($amount, $request->payment_method_id);

            $md = new \ParsedownExtra();
            
            $listing = $user->listings()
                ->create([
                    'title' => $request->title,
                    'slug' => Str::slug($request->title) . '-' . rand(1111, 9999),
                    'company' => $request->company,
                    'logo' => basename($request->file('logo')->store('public')),
                    'location' => $request->location,
                    'apply_link' => $request->apply_link,
                    'content' => $md->text($request->input('content')),
                    'is_highlighted' => $request->filled('is_highlighted'),
                    'is_active' => true
                ]);
                
            **foreach (explode(',', $request->tags) as $requestTag) {
                $tag = Tag::firstOrCreate([
                    'slug' => Str::slug(trim($requestTag))
                ], [
                    'name' => ucwords(trim($requestTag))
                ]);
                $tag->listings()->attach($listing->id);
            }**


            foreach (explode(',', $request->service) as $requestService) {
                $service = Service::firstOrCreate([
                    'service_name' => ucwords(trim($requestService))
                ]);

                 $service->listings()->attach($listing->id);
            }
            
            return redirect()->route('user.dashboard')->with('success', 'Anuntul tau a fost publicat!');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return redirect()->back()
                ->withErrors(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }        

    }  $tag->listings()->attach($listing->id);
            }
```

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $listing = Listing::findOrFail($id);



        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->id == $listing->user_id) {
            $listing = DB::table('listings')
                ->where('id', $id)
                ->first();


            return view('listings.edit', compact('listing'));
        } else {
            return (redirect('/dashboard'));
        }
    }
```

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //working in progress...
        $this->validate($request,[
            'title' => 'required',
            'company' => 'required',
            'logo' => 'file|max:2048|required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
            'location' => 'required',
            'apply_link' => 'required|url',
            'content' => 'required'
            // 'payment_method_id' => 'required'
        ]);


        $data = Listing::find($id);
        $data->title = $request->title;
        $data->company = $request->company;
        $data->logo = basename($request->file('logo')->store('public'));
        $data->location = $request->location;
        $data->apply_link = $request->apply_link;
       
     $data['tags'] = explode(',', $request->tags); // <-this one

        
        $data->content= $request->content;
        // $data['is_highlighted'] = $request->is_highlighted;

        $data['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
        $data->save();
        // DB::table('listings')->where('id', $id)->update($data);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'success');
    }
```

Comment: What is the database error? can you check the storage/logs?

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tags' in 'field list' (SQL: update `listings` set `logo` = X7hKCV7pbeRXOkDKhIG97boFtFs3KMtAYFzTdWsF.jpg, `tags` = ["splash","inot"], `listings`.`updated_at` = 2022-07-11 06:17:31 where `id` = 29)